# Java: Getting ExceptionInInitializerError for Enums

Tags: java, pointers, exception, enums, null

EDIT: Solved but I don't understand why

In PokemonEnum I had this line

```
private PokemonEnum[ ] pokemon = PokemonEnum.values();
```

I changed it to:

```
private static PokemonEnum[ ] pokemon = PokemonEnum.values();
```

and now it works. I never even used that array yet so I don't know why I was getting errors or why static fixed it.

---

I haven't really worked with Enums so I don't really know why I get an ExceptionInInitializerError when I run main (on line 28 when I try to create a new Pokemon). Anyone care to explain please? Thanks.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Pokemon {

    private PokemonEnum name;
    private int dexNumber;
    private BufferedImage sprite;
    private TypeEnum[] types = new TypeEnum[1];
    private ArrayList<AbilityEnum> abilities;
    private ArrayList<MoveEnum> moves;
    private short hp;
    private short attack;
    private short defense;
    private short special_attack;
    private short special_defense;
    private short speed;

    public Pokemon(PokemonEnum name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.dexNumber = name.getDexNum();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Pokemon pikachu = new Pokemon(PokemonEnum.Pikachu);
        System.out.println(pikachu.dexNumber);
    }
}



   public enum PokemonEnum {
    Pikachu;

    public int getDexNum()
    {
        return ordinal()+1;
    }

    private PokemonEnum[ ] pokemon = PokemonEnum.values(); 
}


Stack Trace:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at Pokemon.main(Pokemon.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at PokemonEnum.values(PokemonEnum.java:1)
    at PokemonEnum.<init>(PokemonEnum.java:722)
    at PokemonEnum.<clinit>(PokemonEnum.java:2)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Enumeration is similar to declaring an int final (giving the variable a specific numeric value). Your variable is not initialized to a value so I believe that is where your getting the compiler error

Comment: Please, post full stack trace

Comment: Added, just note that my orignal enum contails like 600 pokemon names, so thats why the numbers are high.

Comment: Do you run your code via an IDE? Did you try to recompile everything? What about putting the minimal code sample in a compilable gist or on ideone?

Comment: Can you please attach TypeEnum,AbilityEnum,MoveEnum

Comment: Is there is any static block in your code..

Comment: It turns out that I did this in PokemonEnum:

private PokemonEnum[ ] pokemon = PokemonEnum.values();

when it should be static and that's what caused it... still don't understand why though

Answer (score 4):

What you are experiencing is 'like' a recursion.

This error occurs because the code `PokemonEnum.values()` is in the enum `PokemonEnum` and when this is compiling it reads `values()` and then using this internal function, the primitive data type `enum` references to itself. However due to the fact that the `enum` is still being compiled, the value of `value()` is `null`.

**Note:** Trying to use the `value()` inside of it's enum will result in an Error. Such that trying to use `if(PokemonEnum.values()!=null)` or even trying to catch the `ExceptionInInitializerError` will not work due to the `values()` being part of a primitive type(*meaning the method being called is `native`*).

**The Solution** would be to place `private PokemonEnum[] pokemon = PokemonEnum.values();` outside and below the enum `PokemonEnum`.

I know this from personal experience as well as other sources on similar problems.

Similar Sources: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447545/creating-a-final-java-class-array-of-enum-constants-with-values) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34972099/java-lang-exceptionininitializererror-in-enum-with-multiple-values#)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had a similar issue trying to reference `this` from the constructor.  Instead I just moved the conditional logic to an `init()` function that returned `this` and then called `MyEnum.MY_TYPE.init()`.