# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError in enum with multiple values

Tags: java, android, enums

This is the code of enum (inside of singleton class):

```
public class GlobalStore extends Application{
.....
......
.....
public synchronized static GlobalStore getInstance() {
    if(instance==null){
        instance = new GlobalStore();
    }
    return instance;
}

.....
......

public static enum Category {
    CATEGORIA_DB(1,instance.getString(R.string.cat_dep_bel),"db"),
    CATEGORIA_EL(2,instance.getString(R.string.cat_edu_lec),"el"),
    CATEGORIA_E(3,instance.getString(R.string.cat_entre),"e"),
    CATEGORIA_EM(4,instance.getString(R.string.cat_est_mod),"em"),
    CATEGORIA_GV(5,instance.getString(R.string.cat_gas_vinos),"gv"),
    CATEGORIA_DH(6,instance.getString(R.string.cat_dis_hog),"dh"),
    CATEGORIA_S(7,instance.getString(R.string.cat_salud),"s"),
    CATEGORIA_ST(8,instance.getString(R.string.cat_ser_tec),"st"),
    CATEGORIA_T(9,instance.getString(R.string.cat_turis),"t"),
    CATEGORIA_AC(10,instance.getString(R.string.cat_arte_cultura),"ac");


    private final int id;
    private final String gloss;
    private final String code;

    Category(int mId, String mGloss, String mCode) {
        this.id = mId;
        this.gloss = mGloss;
        this.code = mCode;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getGloss() {
        return gloss;
    }

    public String getImagen() {
        return "icon_"+code;
    }

    public String getSelectedImagen() {
        return this.getImagen() + "_red";
    }

    public String getDrawString() {
        return "mn_"+code+"1";
    }

}
```

and the error in this line:

```
public static Category findCategoryById(int mId) {

    for (Category categoria : Category.values()) { //HERE is error in Category.values() -- line 327
        if (categoria.getId()==mId) {
            return categoria;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

.....
}
```

UPDATE

the error in logcat:

```
01-24 05:42:49.310 31800-31800/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-24 05:42:49.310 31800-31800/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.assertsoft.beneplus.alpha, PID: 31800
01-24 05:42:49.310 31800-31800/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
01-24 05:42:49.310 31800-31800/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.assertsoft.model.GlobalStore.findCategoriaById(GlobalStore.java:327)
01-24 05:42:49.310 31800-31800/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.assertsoft.adapters.ListaCuponesAdapter.getView(ListaCuponesAdapter.java:196)
```

Comment: could you share the stacktrace

Comment: 'instance' must be null, has getInstance() been called yet?

Comment: @IanMc getInstance has been called: String stringDrawable = "R.drawable."+ GlobalStore.getInstance().findCategoriaById(item.getId_categoria()).getDrawString();
    int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(stringDrawable, "drawable", context.getPackageName());

Comment: Is there any chance one of the R.string.cat_* is not defined?

Comment: @IanMc is defined... i find the solution, see below. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code here:

```
Category(int mId, String mGloss, String mCode) {
        this.id = mId;
        this.gloss = mGloss;
        this.code = mCode;
    }
```

expects three values to be initialised. But this line :

```
public static Category findCategoryById(int mId)
```

is initialising just one out of those. In that static context all the parameters needs to be initialised.

Comment: findCategoryById need go throw the all enum values then Category.values() fails when trying to initialize... but i don't know how it is initialized correctly in this case

Answer (score -1):

The problem was CATEGORIA_XX(N,**instance.getString(R.string.cat_mmm)**,"YY")

getString activity needs to interpret the getString.

CATEGORIA_XX(N,**ActivityInstance.getString(R.string.cat_mmm)**,"YY")

It's Works well!.

Many thanks to all.