# How to Autowired multiple interface implementations and use Map and Enum as a key

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, java-11

For example, there is a task, without violating the **Open/Closed principle**, to safely add new implementations for sending messages in different ways.  The input comes with a parameter that contains the type of "transport" for sending messages or the device where the messages will arrive.

As an input parameter, you need to use Enum, but design the system so that you do not use switch when the parameter comes as a string, but immediately call the desired service in accordance with the stated conditions.

Here is my implementation.

- Test

```java
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class NotificationMasterTest extends MultiImplementationInterfacesAndEnumApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private NotificationMaster notification;

    @Test
    void send() {

        String phone = "phone";

        TypeCommunication typeCommunication =
                TypeCommunication.valueOf("phone");//Runtime Exception

        notification.send(TypeCommunication.PHONE);
    }
}
```

- enum

```java
public enum TypeCommunication {

    PHONE("phone"),
    EMAIL("email"),
    KAFKA("kafka");

    private String value;

    TypeCommunication(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }


    public String getType() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

- interface

```java
public interface Notification {

    void sendNotice();

    TypeCommunication getType();
}
```

- PhoneImplementation

```java
@Service
public class NotificationPhoneImpl implements Notification {

    private final TypeCommunication typeCommunication = TypeCommunication.PHONE;

    public NotificationPhoneImpl() {
    }

    @Override
    public void sendNotice() {
        System.out.println("Send through --- phone---");
    }

    @Override
    public TypeCommunication getType() {
        return this.typeCommunication;
    }
}
```

- EmailEmplementation

```java
@Service
public class NotificationEmailImpl implements Notification {

    private final TypeCommunication typeCommunication = TypeCommunication.EMAIL;

    @Override
    public void sendNotice() {
        System.out.println("Send through --- email ---");
    }

    @Override
    public TypeCommunication getType() {
        return this.typeCommunication;
    }
}
```

- master

```java
package com.example.multi.implementation.interfaces.services;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

@Component
public class NotificationMaster {

    private  Map<TypeCommunication, Notification> notificationService = new HashMap<>();

    private Set<Notification> notification;

    public NotificationMaster(Set<Notification> notification) {
        this.notification = notification;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init(){
        notification.stream()
                .forEach(service -> {
                    TypeCommunication type = service.getType();
                    notificationService.put(type, service);
                });
    }

    public void send(TypeCommunication typeCommunication) {
        Notification notification = notificationService.get(typeCommunication);
        notification.sendNotice();
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to pass a string and convert it to Enum on the fly (without using switch)  and immediately get the desired implementation.

Maybe there is a more flexible solution in which Spring would have already prepared the components without me, so that I don't use Postconstruct and manually create a map with different service implementations?

Comment: Do you want `"phone"` to be automatically de-serialized to enum `TypeCommunication.PHONE`
or you want to get a `Map<TypeCommunication, Notification>` automatically without using `@PostConstruct`? Sorry your requirements is not clear to me

Comment: ........want to get a Map<Type Communication, Notification> automatically without using @PostConstruct. thus, when I pass a string to the method, and call TypeCommunication typeCommunication =
                Type Communication.value Of("phone"), then from Map by key, I will get the desired service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that it cannot be done "on the fly". So, I would create a static `Map` and static method `getByType` in `TypeCommunication` to retrieve the enum by its value:

```java
public enum TypeCommunication {

    PHONE("phone"),
    EMAIL("email"),
    KAFKA("kafka");

    private static final Map<String, TypeCommunication> TYPE_COMMUNICATION_MAP;

    private final String value;

    static {
        TYPE_COMMUNICATION_MAP = Arrays.stream(TypeCommunication.values())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(TypeCommunication::getType, Function.identity(),
                        (existing, replacement) -> existing));
    }

    TypeCommunication(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public static TypeCommunication getByType(String type) {
        return TYPE_COMMUNICATION_MAP.get(type);
    }
}
```

If you received this value in the controller in the request body, then you could use   `@JsonValue` annotation on the `getType()` method to immediately [deserialize](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-enums) it in the enum by the value.

About your `NotificationMaster`, spring cannot collect such a map automatically, but you can collect your map right in constructor without using `@PostConstruct`, and using [`Collectors.toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.function.Supplier)) method, also take the `EnumMap`, since your key is `Enum`:

```java
@Component
public class NotificationMaster {

    private final Map<TypeCommunication, Notification> map;

    public NotificationMaster(List<Notification> notifications) { // or Set
        map = notifications.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Notification::getType, Function.identity(),
                        (existing, replacement) -> existing,
                        () -> new EnumMap<>(TypeCommunication.class)));
    }


    public void send(TypeCommunication typeCommunication) {
        map.getOrDefault(typeCommunication, new DefaultNotificationImpl()).sendNotice();
    }

    private static class DefaultNotificationImpl implements Notification {
        @Override
        public void sendNotice() {
            // some logic, e.g. throw new UnsupportedOperationException
        }

        @Override
        public TypeCommunication getType() {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

It also good to define the `DefaultNotificationImpl` to avoid `NullPointerException` in your `send` method and using now `Map#getOrDefault` method instead of `Map#get`.

You can also take out the logic for creating a map in a separate configuration class and then simple autowire this map in `NotificationMaster`:

```java
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public Map<TypeCommunication, Notification> createMap(List<Notification> notifications) {
        return notifications.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Notification::getType, Function.identity(),
                        (existing, replacement) -> existing,
                        () -> new EnumMap<>(TypeCommunication.class)));
    }
}

@Component
public class NotificationMaster {

    @Autowired
    private Map<TypeCommunication, Notification> map;

    ...
}
```

Comment: it works great. could you explain why it is necessary to use a static construction in Enum?   Is this somehow related to the work of Applicationcontext when dependencies are being implemented? And why did you use EnumMap? Could you reveal the course of your thoughts in these conditions ?

Comment: It's not related to the context, so, it's static because otherwise we will get a `NullPointerException` due to `values()` method call, more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447545/creating-a-final-java-class-array-of-enum-constants-with-values). Besides, it's simple not very logical to retrive desired instance by value using some another instance:)

Comment: About `EnumMap`, so, if your keys are enums, considered good practice to use `EnumMap`, as [documentaion](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumMap.html) says, e.g., this representation is extremely compact and efficient.